# How to calculate: convert 4 2D midpoint coordinates into a 3D rectangular quad polygon

Tags: math, arduino, 3d, 2d, computational-geometry

From an Arduino IR camera, I am capturing the 4 2D midpoints (left middle, right middle, top middle, down middle) of a perfect rectangle (I know its W/H ratio). Do you know how to calculate the 3D coordinates of this quad, and/or calculate any other 2D point 3D coordinates in this quad rectangle space?

I need this to try to find the position of a fifth point coordinates in space relative to this 3D quad space (a bit like raycasting I guess).
I already know how to get the distance and angle between each midpoints, along with the center of the rectangle.
I'm also guessing the best practice would be to put the Z axis origin either at the quad center point or the camera center, and find the other points Z relative to that.
But that's where I am stuck, I don't know how to find the other coordinates, how to deal with the lack of Z and the perspective.

Comment: I suppose the 2D coordinates are in the image, and 3D is in "the real world". To do that usually you need to have the projection matrix of your camera (this matrix is what you get when you calibrate your camera). You can have it using a pinhole model.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, indeed the 2D is the image shoot by the camera, and 3D in real world. The cam is giving me just 4 points with x and y coordinates, no matrix.
I did look into the projection matrix concept, but I found how to get the 2D points from the 3D coordinate objects, not the opposite.
I though since the object I am aiming is perfectly rectangular, I could manage to find an estimation of the 3D coordinates by triangulation.
but it seems quite hard to achieve sadly :/

Comment: When doing such projection from a real camera, it is always good to have the projection matrix for 3D to 2D projection cause it can take lens distortion into account etc. The reverse opperation is very hard because you need assumption on how far the point is from the camera. 2D to 3D convertion at best gives you a straight line. You can try to figure out something using invariate cross-ratio : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio which are invariate in projection

Comment: Thanks, that a good info.
For my setup, I forgot to say but I know the camera viewing angle, it 33 degree horizontal and 23 degree vertical.
knowing the real size and aspect ratio of my rectangle, I might be able to figure out the distance and the orientation of the camera from the orientations of the rectangle diagonal and vertical, and the length of each side, but I just don't know how :(

Comment: Also we can safely assume that the rectangle center will be at the center of the camera.

Comment: Does your camera have distortion?

Comment: it doesn't seem so from what I tested, and with the low viewing angle and the distance from the IR led to the camera, it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Good, good. It's hard for me to figure out your setup, but my advise would be to try to draw your setup like a pinhole model, and then apply so geometry like cross-ratio and thales theorem to find the distance you're looking for. If you could share it, I might be able to help.

Comment: Yes you are right, I was thinking of drawing it too, it would be a lot easier to understand :P